# Android action bar overlay & hidden by default in xml

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I need to have the action bar hidden on application start. Then, after some user action, it has to show up again overlaying the content. Currently I turn it off in a custom style by setting `<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>`, and then call

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
getActionBar().hide();
```

in onCreate() of the activity.
That seems a little awkward though. Can I do all of it in xml configs?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the hiding part, but you cna style the ActionBar as an overlay in your apps theme like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This way it will be visible when starting the activity, that's not what I want

Comment: You can always hide the action bar in the onCreate method of your activity.